# How can Theme.NoTitleBar inherit all attributes of Theme?

Tags: android, themes

Theme.NoTitleBar is defined as below.

```
<style name="Theme.NoTitleBar"> // It does not have parent="Theme"
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

But, it inherits all attributes of Theme.
I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It inherits all attributes of `Theme` because it's basically an *extension* of that theme. It's somewhat similar to saying `Class A extends B`, although there are no distinctions in the visibility of attributes or anything.

Note how `Theme.NoTitleBar` is prefixed with `Theme`, that's where all the attributes come from.

Generally, the `name` of a style provides a hierarchical approach to structuring and naming styles and substyles. You can use the hierarchical characteristic as an alternative to the `parent` attribute for styles you've defined yourself. For extending existing platform-defined styles, you always need to use `parent`.

All this is explained pretty well in the [Styles and Themes documentation, subsection Inheritance](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Inheritance). Two relevant quotes that summarize most of above:

> If you want to inherit from styles that you've defined yourself, you
>   *do not* have to use the parent attribute. Instead, just prefix the name
>   of the style you want to inherit to the name of your new style,
>   separated by a period.
>
> Note: This technique for inheritance by chaining together names only
>   works for styles defined by your own resources. You can't inherit
>   Android built-in styles this way. To reference a built-in style, such
>   as `TextAppearance`, you must use the `parent` attribute.

Head over to the link for more details or to see some examples.